# A way of shortening the writing into a file for multiple arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume I have the following writing code:

```
import pickle
with open('arr1.bin', mode='w') as file:
    pickle.dump(arr1, file)
file.close()

with open('arr2.bin', mode='w') as file:
    pickle.dump(arr2, file)
file.close()
```

Is there a way to merge the writing of `arr1` and `arr2` into one writing function? I want to do that because my code more will be involving plenty of arrays so I thought to make reading and writing throughout my codes more elegant.

Thank you

Comment: Write a function for it?

Comment: You can remove file.close() as the with statement already does this.

Comment: @trincot I just don't know WHAT to return from the function. I am SORRY but I am a beginner programmer :(

Comment: A function does not have to return anything if you don't need it to.

Comment: You need to show us some more code. What are the arrays, what are you doing then... etc...etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## call function file_writing

```
import pickle
def file_writing(arr, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        pickle.dump(arr, file)
file_writing(arr1,'arr1.bin')
file_writing(arr2,'arr2.bin')
file_writing(arr3,'arr3.bin')
```

Comment: hope this helps

Comment: Just to add, since the poster asked about the return value in the comments above:
The function doesn't _need_ a return value. If you omit the `return` statement, a python def will return `None`. And since the return value isn't used by the the statement calling the function it simply disappears.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I have to close the file inside the fucntion `file.close()`?

Comment: No. When you use `with` to open a file the `.close` is implied.